# Creacion de llave foranea incorrectamente formada en laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

En laravel 8, soy nuevo pero estoy intentando crear una tabla llamada "marital_statuses" la cual contiene los estados civiles de las personas ( en este caso "amigos" ( la aplicacion guarda amigos ) ); y tambien una tabla llamada "friends" la cual contiene los amigos, todo esto a traves de migraciones. Ahora bien quiero que en la tabla "friends" se realize una relacion con la tabla "marital_statuses" para asi poder asignar a cada amigo su estado civil, ahora en la migracion "create_friend_table" tengo:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('friends', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('marital_status_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('lastname');

        $table
            ->foreign('marital_status_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('marital_statuses')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

y en la de "create_marital_status_table" tengo:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('marital_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('value');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Ahora ejecuto:

```sh
$ php artisan migrate
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error:

```sh
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `friends`.`friends` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `friends` add constraint `friends_marital_status_id_foreign` foreign key (`marital_status_id`) references `marital_statuses` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

Comment: Un posible problema sería que la migración de Friends se ejecute antes, como marital_statuses no existe en ese momento se produce un error. Normalmente creo las tablas sin claves foráneas y luego en una tercera migración las género.

Comment: Tu error está en el tipo de dato de la llave foránea, ve a la doc y checa la sintaxis adecuada

Comment: @FabianM estabas totalmente en lo correcto!, me di cuenta que el error radicaba en que estaba haciendo la migracion de `friends` antes que la migracion de `marital_statuses`, en cuento a lo que me dice @BetaM era cierto pero no a la vez, es decir funciono con los tipos de datos que dices estan malos pero no eran los que se deben usar correctamente!

Comment: primero tienes que crear la tabla "marital_statuses" porque "friends" necesita de esta para poder crear la relacion y lo otro es que tienes que ver los formatos de los id tienen que ser igual con su referencia Ejemplo: si tienes un id unsignedBigInteger en "marital_statuses" tambien tiene que tener el mismo formato en la clave foranea que esta en "friends"